# Cannot add email account in thunderbird 78

Tags: email, thunderbird

I cannot add a new email account in TB78, but can in 68. I tried 2 different ISPs. TB hangs checking the password. Help? Where would I start looking?  I know this is vague but hoped to get at least a pointer where to look.

This is on ubuntu 2020.10.

Finally, I tried posting this to reddit r/thunderbird, but the moderator removed it.  Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it failing on automatic configuration? If so, try manual configuration.

Comment: as @GrahamNye, automatic configuration fails on some type of accounts. E.G., "...@verizon.net" may refer to an AOL.com server...